# Connection to Outlook Mail server with password but not with auth token using OAuth2

Tags: java, email, oauth-2.0, office365, jakarta-mail

I am using Java Mail to connect to a MS Outlook Mail Server.  I can do so successfully using PLAIN authentication with a username and password. I have heard that Microsoft will disable Basic Authentication soon, so I want to upgrade to use OAuth2.0 rather.

I do the following using a username (email address) and password, which connects successfully:

```java
Store store = null;

String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
Properties props= new Properties();

props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.port", port);
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.login.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port", port);
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
session.setDebug(true);

store = session.getStore("imaps");
logger.info("OAUTH2 IMAP trying to connect with system properties to Host:" + host + ", Port: "+ port + ", userEmailId: " + userEmailId+ ", AccessToken: " + oauth2AccessToken);
try {
    Integer iPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
    store.connect(host, iPort, userEmailId, password);
    // store.connect(host, iPort, userEmailId, oauth2AccessToken);
    logger.info("IMAP connected with system properties to Host:" + host + ", Port: "+ port + ", userEmailId: " + userEmailId+ ", AccessToken: " + oauth2AccessToken);
    if(store.isConnected()){
        logger.info("Connection Established using imap protocol successfully !");
    } else {
        logger.info("Connection not Established using imap protocol");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Store.Connect failed with the errror: "+e.getMessage());
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
    String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
    logger.error(exceptionAsString);
}
return store;
```

However, if I change it to use the the OAuth2 Token instead of the password to connect, it is unsuccessful:

```java
store.connect(host, iPort, userEmailId, oauth2AccessToken);
```

Debug:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.0-b01
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0-b01
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: disable AUTH=LOGIN
DEBUG IMAPS: disable AUTH=PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAPS: enable SASL
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL mechanisms allowed: XOAUTH2


DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [XXXX]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=username@email.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL Mechanisms:
DEBUG IMAPS:  XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: 
DEBUG IMAPS: No SASL support
A1 LOGIN username@email.com {1479+}
XXXXX
A1 NO LOGIN failed.
```

Azure Portal message using Auth Token, looks like it expecting a password and not a token:

[image]

So, it cannot connect using the OAuth2 Authentication token.

The token is created as follows, which returns a string that looks like a valid token:

```java
String accessToken = null;
String clientId = "<client id from azure app registration>"
String secret = "<client secret from azure app registration>" - client secret value
String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id from azure>/oauth2/v2.0/token";
String scope = "https://outlook.office365.com/.default";

try {
    ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(clientId, ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(secret)).authority(authority).build();

    // With client credentials flows the scope is ALWAYS of the shape "resource/.default", as the
    // application permissions need to be set statically (in the portal), and then granted by a tenant administrator
    ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(scope)).build();

    CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
    IAuthenticationResult result = future.get();
    accessToken = result.accessToken();
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(accessToken)) {
        logger.error("Access token "+accessToken);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error("Exception in acquiring token: "+e.getMessage(), e);
}
logger.debug("Access Token : "+accessToken);
return accessToken;
```

How do I change this to to connect to the mail server using OAuth2.0?

Comment: Have you looked at https://jakartaee.github.io/mail-api/OAuth2 for instructions how to use OAuth2 with JakartaMail?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the reply. I have looked, and I cannot find  any examples on how to access MS Outlook (there are examples for Gmail). So I have upgraded to `javax.mail 1.6.2` (with `jakarta.mail 2.0.1` the api I use doesn't compile, e.g. there's no `Store`, etc.), and changed to the example in the link you sent for 'JavaMail 1.5.5 and later' using `store.connect("imap-mail.outlook.com", username, oauth2AccessToken);`, but it still fails: `DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.`.

Comment: JakartaMail 1.6 vs 2.0 is whether it uses javax.* or jakarta.* for the package names. In any case, the latest JakartaMail 1.6 is 1.6.7. And the release notes do mention some OAuth related changes for Microsoft in 1.6.6 (for POP3, so it may not be related), see https://jakartaee.github.io/mail-api/docs/CHANGES.txt